# Parser to verify declarations of type int and float in C language

Tags: parsing, bison, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

I'm trying to write a parser to verify the following declarations of type int and float in C language.
variables declarations, pointer variable declarations, array of any dimensions

1. float a , b , r = 5, area = r * r , * b;
2. int a , b , c , ** p ;
3. int x , mat [2][3];

This is my lex file

```
    %{
    #include "y.tab.h"
    extern int yylval;
    %}

    %%
    "int" return INT;
    "float" return FLOAT;
    [0-9]+ return NUM; 
    [_|a-z|A-Z]([_|a-z|A-Z|0-9])*{1,255} return NAME;
    [+\-*/] return op;

    [ \t\n];
    .   return yytext[0];
    %%
```

This is my yacc file

```
    %{
    #include<stdio.h>
    int yylex() ;
    int yyerror();
    %}

    %token NUM NAME op INT FLOAT
    %%

    stmt_list: stmt | stmt_list stmt;
    stmt: type id_list ';' { printf("Valid Declaration\n"); };   
    type: INT | FLOAT;
    id_list: id ',' id_list | id ;
    id: NAME'='expr | expr;
    expr: expr op expr | POINT expr | expr MATRIX | '(' expr')' | NAME;
    MATRIX: '[' NUM ']' |  '[' NUM ']' MATRIX ; 
    POINT: '*' | '*'POINT;
    %%
    int main(){
      yyparse();
      return 0;
    }
    int yyerror(){
      printf("Invalid Declaration\n");
      return -1;
    }
```

Even if I enter "int a;" as input, I get "Invalid Declaration". I'm not able to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: 1. A vertical bar in a character class is just another character. So many of your character classes incorrectly accept vertical bar characters. 2. The format of a rule in flex is `<pattern><whitespace><action>`. All three parts are mandatory, including the whitespace.

Comment: I updated expr to derive NUM as well. Everything is working fine except pointers. "int *p" is being rejected.

Comment: What does your lexer return when it encounters a `*`? (By the way, you can get flex to tell you which rules it is matching, and you can get bison to tell you what tokens it is receiving. See the `-d` option to flex and the `-t` option to bison in their respective manuals.)

Comment: What do you mean "verify"?  WIthout that being clear, this question is unanswerable.   Don't make us guess.